# Group-Object - divide large group into chunks

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that retrieves some data from a database, uses `Group-Object` to collect it into similar groups, then uses `foreach` to act on each group.

The trouble is that some groups have more than 100 items, but my process can only act on 100 at once. It was written specifically to handle the items in the `Group-Object` results and I'd rather not rewrite that part.

Is there some elegant way to have `Group-Object` break up the groups into at most 100 items at a time? Or do I have to collect them with a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with, partially thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26850233/864696):

```
# create hashtable with unique basedomain as key and zero as value
$NameHash = @{};
foreach ($i in $tbl.rows | Group-Object basedomain) {
  $NameHash[$i.Name]=0;
}
# regroup using the hashtable as a counter source
$result = $tbl.rows | Group-Object basedomain, { [math]::Floor($NameHash[$_.basedomain]++ / 100) }
```

Comment: Actually, I simplified it further. Now the SQL that generates the data will itself use a hash function to put the members into bins.